# How can I use a variable inside a RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var string = "This is a string";
var key = "Th"; 
var patt = new RegExp(/\b key /, "i");

if(patt.test(string)){
    alert("true");
}
```

How can I escape \b so I can use the `key` variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn´t `indexOf` be enough? `(string.indexOf(key) > -1)` ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf or even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression literal when using the RegExp constructor.

When you want a `\` in a string literal, you have to escape it as `\\`.

Here's the code :

```
var patt = new RegExp("\\b " + key + " ", "i");
```

Comment: I'm not positive, but don't you still need the delimiters?

Comment: If you mean the `/`, they're what defines a regular expression literal. So no, you can't use them when you want to use a variable.